# Approximate the typical value of a sample

Tags: algorithm, median, approximation

Say I have a sample of N positive real numbers and I want to find a "typical" value for these numbers. Of course "typical" is not very well defined but one could think of the following more concrete problem :

The numbers are distributed such that (roughly speaking) a fraction (1-epsilon) of them is drawn from a Gaussian with positive mean m > 0 and mean square deviation sigma << m and a small fraction epsilon of them is drawn from some other distribution, heavy tailed both for large and small numbers. I want to estimate the mean of the Gaussian within a few standard deviation.

A solution would be to compute the median but while it is O(N), constant factors are not so good for moderate N and moreover it requires quite a bit of coding. I am ready to give up precision on my estimate against code simplicity and/or small N performance (say N is 10 or 20 for instance, and I have at most one or two outliers).

Do you have any suggestion ?

(For instance, if my outliers where only coming from large values, I would compute the average of the log of my values and exponentiate it. Under some further assumptions this gives me, generally, a good estimate and I can compute it easily and with a sharp O(N)).

Comment: The Gaussian component is symmetric about the mean.  If your heavy tailed component is also symmetric with the same mean, then it should affect the variance but not the mean or median, and the mean and median should be equal to each other by symmetry.  In that case I'd suggest using good old X-bar.

Comment: I was thinking about positive numbers so my heavy tailed part would be something like P(x) = 1/2 x^{0.5} 1(x>1) + 1/2 x^{-0.5} 1(x<1) so the heavy tailed part 1) is not symmetric 2) does not have a mean 3) does not need to have the same mode. Thanks for the suggestion though !

Comment: What about doing a normal probability plot and excluding all the values that fall off the line in the tails?

Comment: I don't want to sort my array, otherwise I could just do it and take the median.

Comment: If the non-Gaussian component isn't symmetric and doesn't share the same mean, then the median of all the data isn't necessarily near the mean of the Gaussian.

Comment: As I said the non-Gaussian component does not need to have a mean. I suspect you are thinking of N ->oo while I want to deal with N finite and not too large. Of course this makes thing be ill defined but say that with good probability (that goes to one when N -> oo or epsilon ->0) the median will be within a constant standard deviation of the mean of the Gaussian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the mean of the numbers excluding the min and max. The formula is (sum - min - max) / (N - 2), and the terms in the numerator can be computed simply with one pass (watch out for floating point issues though).

Comment: Thanks, I actually thought about that, but what I did not like is that it is still quite sensible to the number of outliers. Well I could generalize your approach and remove the xN smallest values and xN largest values for some well chosen x (something like a few epsilon). But then it gets a bit more involved to code and a bit less efficient.

 However I realize that I am maybe just asking for too much and maybe your suggestion is the best. Let's see what other suggest !

Answer (score 1):

I think you should reconsider the median, either using quickselect or [Blum-Floyd-Pratt-Rivest-Tarjan](http://moonflare.com/code/select/select.pdf) (as implented here by Coetzee). It's fast and robust.

If you need better speed you might consider picking a fixed number of random elements and taking their median. This is sublinear (O(1) or O(log n) depending on the model) and works well for large sets.